# Avoiding Duplicate Column Name Additions in a TDataSet

Tags: delphi, pascal, tdataset

I am dynamically adding fields to a TDataSet using the following code:

```
while not ibSQL.Eof do
   fieldname := Trim(ibSql.FieldByName('columnnameofchange').AsString);
   TDataSet.FieldDefs.Add(fieldname , ftString, 255);
end
```

Problem is that I might get duplicate names so what is the easiest way to screen for duplicates and not add the duplicates that are already added.

I hope not to traverse through the TDataSet.FieldDefList for each column added as this would be tedious for every single column addition.  And there can be many additions.

Please supply another solution if possible.  If not then I am stuck using the FieldDefList iteration.

I will also add that screening out duplicates on the SQL query is an option but not a desired option.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TFieldDefs` has a method `IndexOf` that returns `-1` when a field with the given name does not exist.

Comment: I tried the find method but it brings up a GUI message on the first find attempt that says "Field 'columnnameofchange'not Found" and then the procedure stops dead in its tracks and does not process any more recordsin the SQL.                                                                     if fDataSet.FieldDefs.Find(fieldname) = nil then
              fDataSet.FieldDefs.Add(fieldname, ftString, 255);

Comment: You are right. I must have been mislead by the inherited Find method of TDefCollection. In that case better try IndexOf and check for -1.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the easiest way would probably be to put all of the existing field names in a `TStringList`. You could then check for the existence before adding a new field, and if you add it you simply add the name to the list:

```
var
  FldList: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  FldList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
      FldList.Add(DataSet.Fields[i].FieldName);

    while not ibSQL.Eof do
    begin
      fieldname := Trim(ibSql.FieldByName('columnnameofchange').AsString);
      if FldList.IndexOf(fieldName) = -1 then
      begin
        FldList.Add(fieldName);
        DataSet.FieldDefs.Add(fieldname , ftString, 255);
      end;
      ibSQL.Next;
    end;
  finally
    FldList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this anyway as I finished writing it, but clearly screening on the query was my preference for this problem.

*I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you're aiming for so forgive me if I'm not answering your question. Also, it has been years since I used Delphi regularly so this is definitely not a specific answer.*

If you're using the `TADOQuery` (or whatever TDataSet you're using) in the way I expect my workaround was to do something like:

```
//SQL
SELECT
  a.field1,
  a....   ,
  a.fieldN,
  b.field1 as "AlternateName"
FROM 
  Table a INNER JOIN Table b
WHERE ...
```

As which point it automatically used `AlternateName` instead of `field1` (thus the collision where you're forced to work by index or rename the columns.

Obviously if you're opening a table for writing this isn't a great solution. In my experience with Delphi most of the hardship could be stripped out with simple SQL tricks so that you did not need to waste time playing with the fields.

Essentially this is just doing what you're doing at the source instead of the destination and it is a heck of a lot easier to update.

Comment: Although you describe a valid way to adjust column names in a query, this has nothing to do with the problem described in the question. If you look at the provided source you can see that a result set is iterated where the "field names" are taken from the content of one column. Actually the "field names" represent the data retrieved.

Comment: Yes, nothing to do with the problem. Collisions are acceptable in the data and if you notice I ma turning many vertical data columns into one wide horizontal row.  It is more complicated that that but generally that is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is keep a `TStringList` with `Sorted := true` and `Duplicates := dupError` set.  For each field, do `myStringList.Add(UpperCase(FieldName));` inside a try block, and if it throws an exception, you know it's a duplicate.

`TStringList` is really an incredibly versatile class.  It's always a bit surprising all the uses you can find for it...

Comment: Instead of catching exceptions you should check with `TStrings.IndexOf`

Comment: If it is only the fieldname you need, you can simply set the Stringlist Duplicates to dupIgnore and create the FieldDefs iterating the StringList after the loop. BTW, you don't need the Uppercase unless you set CaseSensitive to true.